# Should I use Apple Push Notification or simply pull data in background for simple app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that fetches data from server via json/http (actually, it synconizes data with Core Data). User needs to be notified when new data is available in 5-10 minutes. I am planning to have about 10 users (that as an internal enterprise app), so I can simply fetch data in background using `NSURLSession`.

But iOS may kill my app in case of low memory (or even user may kill it!), and no notifications would be delivered! So, I believe APN may be used. But this solution looks very complex for such a simple task and small number of users.

Ideally, I should have some service/daemon or (like `IntentService` on android), but I can't have it on iOS, so there are only 2 ways: APN or background app (which may be killed). What is the right way here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your app killed, your app can be opened in background and fetch data. This feature is called as background app refresh. After updating data, you can show user a local notification, which makes it easy by not using APNS. However, if you want to use APNS, you can use Amazon SNS to send push notifications. If i am not remembering wrong, it gives first million push notifications as free for every month. It is very easy to implement, though.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know it. So, what the main purpose of APNS then? Is it for services with million clients (i.e. pushing from Amazon to clients is cheaper than supporting http server for million clients)? Looks like I can stay with BAR, background fetch and ``UILocalNotification``. BTW, do Email client on IOS use BAR? My clients are happy with how email client works, so I can simply do the same.

Comment: When an app receives notification from APNS, it instantly runs the AppDelegate to handle that notification. This means, your app is bootstrapped by the APNS. However, when you use BAR, your app periodically asks for the changes on the server. Beacuse you said it is internal and will be used by 10 people, its the easiest way of doing it. For large projects, periodically asking for something to server creates a load for both app and server, most of the time unnecessary.

Comment: If you use exchange mail, your mail is arrived with a system like APNS but a little bit different. If you want to learn how it works, search for MDM. On the other hand, a pop/imap based mail asks for changes periodically just like an application with BAR functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I know that MS Exchange uses its own protocol even for desktop, I spoke about plain old POP:) I'll stay with BAR because I do not have a lot of users and 5-10 minutes gap is ok for me.